# Sql Join tables and get data from both on same column

Tags: sql-server

**EDIT** Here is my problem simplified

I need data from Sales and References table

Sales returns me data with amount transfered

References returns me data with the amount to supply and is filetered by inventory

Basically i need to get the results that match References but i need to also add the results that do not appear on the References table but these are ignored by the where clause

Here is the actual updated query i used in the beginning

```
SELECT 
    A.Reference,
    B.QtyToSupply,
    A.QtyTransfered
FROM 
    SALES A
RIGHT JOIN 
    REFERENCES B ON A.Reference = B.Reference
WHERE B.InventoryId = 1
```

**UPDATE EXAMPLE**

```
SELECT 
    Reference,
    QtyTransfered
FROM 
    SALES
```

This returns this data:

```
  Reference   |  QtyTransfered
     M1              200
     M1              200
     M2              200
     M4              500
     M5              250
     M6              300
```

The joined query returns this data

```
SELECT 
    A.Reference,
    B.QtyToSupply,
    A.QtyTransfered
FROM 
    SALES A
RIGHT JOIN 
    REFERENCES B ON A.Reference = B.Reference
WHERE B.InventoryId = 1


  Reference   |  QtyToSupply    | QtyTransfered
     M2              200              200
     M4              500              500
     M6              300              300
     M9              800              NULL
     M10             800              NULL
```

With left join

```
Reference   |  QtyToSupply    | QtyTransfered
     M2              200              200
     M4              500              500
     M6              300              300
```

The output should be

```
   Reference   |  QtyToSupply    | QtyTransfered
         M2              200              200
         M4              500              500
         M6              300              300
         M9              800              NULL
         M10             800              NULL
         M1              NULL             200
         M1              NULL             200
         M5              NULL             250
```

**FINAL RESULT**

Here is how i managed to get the result intended despite the confusion since i haven't ever used union before.

```
   SELECT 
        A.Reference,
        B.QtyToSupply,
        A.QtyTransfered
    FROM 
        SALES A
    RIGHT JOIN 
        REFERENCES B ON A.Reference = B.Reference
    WHERE B.InventoryId = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 
        S.Reference,
        R.QtyToSupply,
        S.QtyTransfered
    FROM 
        SALES S
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM References R WHERE R.Reference= S.Reference)
```

.I'll edit the question later to look less confusing for people who go through the same problem

Comment: Could you add some data with expected results? seems the explanation is not clear as you are mentioning about number of rows returned.

Comment: updated with examples to show what i need

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: This is one of the most confusing questions I have ever read, can you edit the question with DDL to create the sample tables [SALES] and [REFERENCES] (which is a keyword and should be discouraged), and also include the output you want?

Comment: i know it's confusing but i alreayd managed to get the result intended, see the final edit on my post. I never used UNION before so i thought i had to do it with join

Comment: For future reference:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2):

You need a full join see following SQL

```
    create table #SALES 
    (
    Reference varchar(5),
    QtyTransfered int
    )

    create table #REFERENCES 
    (
    Reference varchar(5),
    QtyToSupply int
    )

    insert into #SALES
    select 'M1',200 UNION ALL
    select 'M1',200 UNION ALL
    select 'M2',200 UNION ALL
    select 'M4',500 UNION ALL
    select 'M5',250 UNION ALL
    select 'M6',300 

    insert into #REFERENCES 
    select 'M2' ,200 UNION ALL   
    select 'M4' ,500 UNION ALL    
    select 'M6' ,300 UNION ALL    
    select 'M9' ,800 UNION ALL    
    select 'M10',800       

    SELECT 
    COALESCE(b.Reference,a.Reference)Reference,
    B.QtyToSupply,
    A.QtyTransfered
    FROM #SALES A
    full JOIN #REFERENCES B
    ON A.Reference = B.Reference
    order by 2 DESC

    DROP TABLE #REFERENCES
    DROP TABLE #SALES
```

adding the output

```
     Reference QtyToSupply QtyTransfered
    --------- ----------- -------------
    M9        800         NULL
    M10       800         NULL
    M4        500         500
    M6        300         300
    M2        200         200
    M5        NULL        250
    M1        NULL        200
    M1        NULL        200
```

Comment: this won't work because the references that don't exist on table B won't appear

Comment: I am not sure whether you looked at the output of this with the output that you have mentioned. it matches with what you want, if you are expecting different output then i would recommend updating the output

Comment: Added the output for your reference

Comment: See my last edit to my post, i already managed to get the result intended. This was not possible with join only because i had to use union to get the results that don't exist on right table

Comment: I am not sure about your answer "This was not possible with join" which i have already matched the output. so i will leave it up to you to use which one, but joins can be used and i do not see a difference in the output, i updated the output.

Comment: sorry i forgot to update my post but the references table has a foreign key, and while your query does work, when i add the where clause for foreign key ' Where InventoryId = 1'   it won't give me the expected result. I'll update my question later and if after figuring out how to handle the where clause i'll implement this answer

Comment: Sample data also needs to be updated with Column InventoryId data and with the combinations of data. This explains why we need to have clear requirements for implementaion :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you did subqueries along with the UNION ALL....

```
SELECT  A.Reference,
   (SELECT b. qtytosupply FROM "REFERENCES" b where A.Reference = B.Reference) QtyToSupply,
   A.QtyTransfered
FROM SALES A 
union all
SELECT 
   A.Reference,
   A.QtyToSupply,
    (SELECT b.qtytransfered FROM SALES b where A.Reference = B.Reference)  QtyTransfered
FROM "REFERENCES" A
```

Comment: if i do left join the References that do not appear on the right table, won't appear. There are references on the left table that aren't on the right one and i need those to appear on the final result too